# How to reference a variable in previous function?

Tags: python

I am trying to call back the "numberofDays" in the second function, which is an user input while executing the first function. Is there a way to achieve this? Right now it shows 'number of Days is not defined'.

Or should I just combine them into one function?

Thanks!

```
def chooseStockandDays():
    stk = input("Please enter the stock symbol:")
    numberofDays = input("please enter the number of days for the analysis:")
    return generateReport(stk)

def generateReport(stk):
    dt = datetime.date.today()
    dtPast = dt + datetime.timedelta(days=numberofDays)
    print(dt)
    print(dtPast)
```

Comment: you can pass it as an additional parameter

Comment: `generateReport` returns `None`: is that what you want `chooseStockandDays` to return as well?

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as an additional parameter like this:

```
def chooseStockandDays():
    stk = input("Please enter the stock symbol:")
    numberofDays = input("please enter the number of days for the analysis:")
    return generateReport(stk, numberofDays)

def generateReport(stk, numberofDays):
    dt = datetime.date.today()
    dtPast = dt + datetime.timedelta(days=numberofDays)
    print(dt)
    print(dtPast)
```

Comment: That is great help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the numberofDays variable as an additional parameter

```
def chooseStockandDays():
    stk = input("Please enter the stock symbol:")
    numberofDays = input("please enter the number of days for the analysis:")
    return generateReport(stk,numberofDays)

def generateReport(stk,numberofDays):
    dt = datetime.date.today()
    dtPast = dt + datetime.timedelta(days=numberofDays)
    print(dt)
    print(dtPast)
```